# OpenCV - Android - Web Database

Tags: opencv

**How i can get data from database to any object in video, Like Monitor, Face, Computer, KFC Logo, and show a data in a box beside an object**

Thank you

Comment: sorry, but if you can give me a book about it or links, i can't found it :(

Comment: Bakr please see scope of Stack Overflow - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*.

Comment: There are plenty of books on OpenCV.  A simple Google search will show those.